# Stucked installing php7.0-zip extension

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04, php-extension

Im trying to install the extension php7.0-zip (using Ubuntu 16.04), im getting the following message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
php7.0-zip : Depends: libzip2 (>= 0.11.2) but 0.10.1-1.2 is to be installed
```

this is my php version:

```
PHP 7.0.28-1~dotdeb+8.1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.28-1~dotdeb+8.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

i tried to run `sudo apt-get update`, purgue and reinstall libzip2 but the newer version is 0.10.1-1.2 `libzip2 is already the newest version (0.10.1-1.2).`

I don't have a clue of what to do, plz help

Answer (score 0):

libzip4:i386 is a 32-bit package. and conflicts with 64-bit version. are you using a 32-bit computer?

if you are using 64-bit then do:
sudo apt-get purge libzip4

then:

```
sudo apt-get install php-zip
```

if you are using 32-bit then:

```
sudo apt-get install php-zip:i386
```